# Elasticsearch - NotFoundError: NotFoundError(404, 'index_not_found_exception', 'no such index)

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am trying to retrieve documents from an elastisearch index using python. The code for which is below:

```
def get_data_es():
    ES_HOST = {
            "host": "localhost",
            "port": 9200
            }

    ES_INDEX = "radius_ml_posts"
    ES_TYPE = {'author': 'vaibhav'}

    es = Elasticsearch(hosts=[ES_HOST,])
    count = 0
    while True:
        try:
            es.ping()
            print("Elasticsearch server bounded at url: {}".format(es.cat.master().split()[-2]))
            results_gen = elasticsearch.helpers.scan(
                es,
                query={"query": {"match_all": {}}},
                index=ES_INDEX
            )
            break
        except elasticsearch.exceptions.ConnectionError:
            time.sleep(15)
            count += 1
            print("Trying to connect to elasticsearch server. Retry number: {}".format(count))
            print("Connections info: {}".format(es.transport.connection_pool.connections))
    return list(results_gen)
```

When I call this function I get the following error:

```
data = get_data_es()
Elasticsearch server bounded at url: 172.29.0.3
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-39-cd0614623725>", line 1, in <module>
    data = get_data_es()

  File "<ipython-input-38-af72b83dd516>", line 27, in get_data_es
    return list(results_gen)

  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/helpers/actions.py", line 445, in scan
    body=query, scroll=scroll, size=size, request_timeout=request_timeout, **kwargs

  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/client/utils.py", line 92, in _wrapped
    return func(*args, params=params, headers=headers, **kwargs)

  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/client/__init__.py", line 1627, in search
    body=body,

  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/transport.py", line 362, in perform_request
    timeout=timeout,

  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/http_urllib3.py", line 252, in perform_request
    self._raise_error(response.status, raw_data)

  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/base.py", line 282, in _raise_error
    status_code, error_message, additional_info

NotFoundError: NotFoundError(404, 'index_not_found_exception', 'no such index [radius_ml_posts]', radius_ml_posts, index_or_alias)
```

I checked the elasticsearch server and the index itself. They are all up and running fine.

The version of elasticsearch in python is '7.7.0'.

Can you please help in fixing this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to using create_if_not_exists. Then maybe figure out this exception in name of index

Comment: I would appreciate if you can suggest some improvements in the code. I didnt fully understand your suggestion there.